# compute_cartesian_path does not compute continuous joint positions

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS 16.04 in WSL with ROS kinetic.

While calculating several cartesian paths for a staubli_tx260l (6axes industrial robot) with the compute_cartesian_path service, it happens that sometimes the path is invalid, since the joint positions along the paths are not continuous, see for example picture below.

[image: image description]

The flip happens between the 4th and the 5th position, where the robot should move from position

```
[-0.8164353348567588, -1.0937959386772529, 1.4667880334652406, 1.9230484632374774, 0.3627698072434711, 3.9772405581658408]
```

to

```
[2.0767835783263866, -0.4576791782176186, 1.4568906881126429, -2.735827535224531, 1.191242394368736, -0.2624960939982821]
```

This is the MoveIt log:

```
[ INFO] [1560442288.701454600]: Received request to compute Cartesian path
[ INFO] [1560442288.707727800]: Attempting to follow 2 waypoints for link 'robotB_speaker_tcp' using a step of 0.010000 m and jump threshold 0.000000 (in global reference frame)
[ INFO] [1560442288.748145300]: Computed Cartesian path with 15 points (followed 100.000000% of requested trajectory)
```

I am using a custom moveit package for the staubli robot, but the same occurred also with the ur5_moveit_package. So I guess the problem has to do with the planning algorithm rather than the model.

Is this a bug or do I miss some setting?

Thanks in advance!

Best, Romana

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325707/compute_cartesian_path-does-not-compute-continuous-joint-positions/) by [romana](https://answers.ros.org/users/42687/romana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-06-13**:
The `jump_threshold` parameter passed to the [compute_cartesian_path method](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#afd29c4dc55b10564102cf393cd38c71d) is used to control the maximum joint angle jumps between successive joint angles to still be considered a valid path. What are you setting for that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@jarvisschultz:

> and jump threshold 0.000000

so `0`, meaning : disabled, meaning: all joint configurations are acceptable.

> So I guess the problem has to do with the planning algorithm

there is no planning. `compute_cartesian_path(..)` only interpolates.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-06-13**:
@gvdhoorn oops.... didn't read the question carefully enough. That `jump_threshold` is very likely the error. You are also correct that `compute_cartesian_path` does no planning. Only interpolation, collision checking, and joint limit checking.

**Comment by [romana](https://answers.ros.org/users/42687/romana/) on 2019-06-14**:
Thank you very much for your quick reply, this seems obvious now ;)

I changed it and it works now!

While wondering in which situations such a parameter could be of use, I stumbled also over this thread:
https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/773

**Comment by [minhsonpkmta@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36367/minhsonpkmta@gmail.com/) on 2019-06-25**:
hello, i have a problem with add Cartesian to Rviz. im using ros kinetic 16.04.5. Someone help me?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-26**:
@minhsonpkmta@gmail.com: please don't post comments on questions asking for help. You've already posted a question.

**Comment by [minhsonpkmta@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/36367/minhsonpkmta@gmail.com/) on 2019-06-26**:
@gvhhoorn http://answers.ros.org/question/326916/how-to-add-cartesian-path-planner-moveit-plugin-in-rviz/
my question but nobody answers :<

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-26**:
That is still not a reason to post comments on tangentially related questions. If nobody answers, perhaps nobody knows or they don't have time.